# Setting iframe marginheight="0" by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a problem when validating the code of my page. I get error syaing the "marginheight" and marginwidth attributes of my iframe should be set i css instead. I have found out that this cannot be done (am i right)? But it should be possible by using javascript.

I have tried this code, as suggested by another post, but it does not work:

```
document.GetElementById("myIframe").marginheight="0";
```

but `alert(document.GetElementById("myIframe").marginheight="0");` gives me only "undefined"

Do I have to choose between a validated site and an iframe with no margin? or is there a way to get both?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var myFrame = document.GetElementById("myIframe");

myFrame.marginheight="0";
```

Here is a working Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lq5dS/1/

Comment: Fixed fiddle - the reference to the iframe was wrong http://jsfiddle.net/Lq5dS/2/

Before:
var myframe = document.getElementById("myIFrame");
iframe.marginHeight = input.value;

After:
var myframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
myframe.marginHeight = input.value

Answer (score 0):

The iframe properties need to be in camel case:

```
myFrame.marginHeight = "0";
myFrame.marginWidth = "0";
```

GetElementById is also incorrect syntax - it should be

```
document.getElementById
```